# Force Sharepoint to create new document using office web apps

Tags: office-integration, office-web-apps

Is there a way to force Sharepoint 2010 to use office web apps when creating a new word document?

From what I've seen it works like this:
- office web apps will be used if the client computer don't have office installed at all
- if office is installed it really doesn't matter what settings you make in sharepoint, it will still try to create the new document using Office instead of Office web Apps.

The above seems to be true, when I create a new document using my windows computer it will open in Word. If i do the same using my mac and safari it will create a new document using office web apps. If I take a closer look on what's happening the "New Document"-button contains different links depending on my computer. 
However if I take the link that is produced on my mac computer and put it on a page in sharepoint it works on the windows machine with office installed (i.e. new document creates a new document in office web apps).

The link I'm using is this:
/_layouts/createNewDocument.aspx?id=&SaveLocation=&Source=&DefaultItemOpen=1

Any idea on how I get this to work? Either to trick sharepoint in believing that I don't have office installed or to replace the normal "New document"-link with the one above and make it aware of current folder.

Comment: Check this solution: [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7127/unable-to-activate-solution-in-sharepoint-2010-site][1]


  [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7127/unable-to-activate-solution-in-sharepoint-2010-site

Answer (score 3):

I created a blog post about this today: [Create a new document using Office Web Apps](http://www.estruyf.be/blog/create-a-new-document-using-office-web-apps).

ID is the URL to the document template that is associated with the content type. Ex.:

```
http:// www.yourdomain.com/TeamSite/template.docx`
```

SaveLocation is the location to the document library where the document needs to be saved. Ex:

```
&SaveLocation=http:// www.yourdomain.com/TeamSite/Documents
```

Source is the URL to the default view of the document library. Ex.:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/TeamSite/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

The whole url looks like this:

```
http:// www.yourdomain.com/TeamSite/_layouts/CreateNewDocument.aspx?id=http://www.yourdomain.com/TeamSite/template.docx&amp;SaveLocation=http://www.yourdomain.com/TeamSite/Documents&amp;Source=http://www.yourdomain.com/TeamSite/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx&amp;DefaultItemOpen=1
```